# Trouble on saving an associated model and then retrieve some data from that

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, associations

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I am trying to retrieve some data from a just saved child model (associated model) in order to store that data in the parent model.

More precisely (in steps) I would like to do:

1. Save the child model Account of the parent model User
2. Retrieve the just created Account ID value and save that value in the User model attribute named `users_account_id`.

... and more explicitly (in values) I would like to have the following scenario after saving the child model Account:

```
# Account values
Account.id = 222
Account.name = "Test_name"
...
Account.user_id = 111

# User values
User.id = 111
User.users_account_id = 222
```

*I already implemented the first step*, but **how can I implement the second step?**

---

In order to retrieve the Account ID, I tryed to use an association callback

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :account, :before_add => :callback_name


  validates_associated :account
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :account

  def callback_name
    self.users_account_id = Account.find_by_id(self.id).id
  end
end
```

but I get this error:

```
Unknown key(s): before_add
```

Comment: You can only use `before_add` on collections, e.g. `has_many` or `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationships.

Comment: what is it? so strange associations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is way overkill. All you need to do is put the user_id in the form of the account that is getting created as a hidden field.

```
<% form_for(@account) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
<% end %>
```

Of course add your other fields that you want for account and you need a current_user object which you will need anyways with your current logic.

Comment: There is a way less "overkiller" that I can use?

Comment: yes, the code I wrote. It replaces all the the adding user_id stuff unless I'm missing something but I think you just don't really get rails associations and I understand having one's own logic

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to side step your question a bit, and ask why you need IDs pointing in both directions? I assume you want your User to be related to an Account, and an Account to have one or more Users. The "Rails Way" to do this would be something like the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :account
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
end
```

In your database the `users` table will have `account_id` and the `accounts` table will **not** have a user_id of any kind.

This will still allow you to user the association in both directions:

```
some_user.account # Returns the correct account object
some_account.users # Returns all users for the account
```

I hope this helps somewhat!

Comment: (Even if you do not think the same as me about the has_many\belogns_to relationship of accounts and users) In your case I would like to have *also* the 'user_id' *in* the 'account' table...